# SUPEE-9652 ZEND PATCH- DISCUSS ISSUES HERE!

Tags: magento-1.7, supee-9652

Long waiting patch has been released. Seems like a light patch. Discuss installation related issue in this topic!

https://magento.com/tech-resources/downloads/magento/